# C# "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." - happening occasionally

Tags: ssl, dynamics-crm, webclient

This is a request to GoCardless test API from a Dynamics CRM plugin. I receive "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error. It only happens on the first request after some time without sending one. If I send it again, it will be OK. I would appreciate a lot your help.
Here is my code:

```
//I have tried all the following lines in comment without success
//ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

//ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
//ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
string baseURL = "https://api-sandbox.gocardless.com/";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + t);
client.Headers.Add("GoCardless-Version", "2015-07-06");
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
Customers model = new Customers();            
customer.country_code = "GB";            
model.customers = customer;

MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customers));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, model);
stream1.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);

// Apply ASCII Encoding to obtain the string as a byte array. 
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());

ReturnedCustomers result = new ReturnedCustomers();
 //Upload the input string using the HTTP 1.0 POST method. 
try
{
    byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(baseURL + "customers", "POST", byteArray);
    string responseText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ReturnedCustomers));

    using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(responseText))
    {
        result = (ReturnedCustomers)serializer.ReadObject(s);
    }
}
catch (WebException exception)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx) are the following limitations:

1. Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
2. Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
3. IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
4. Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended.
   5.There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.

The error may be due to seguneti things:

1. The certificate is invalid
2. The certification authority is not public
3. Could you check what is the value of ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue and ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol attributes in your environment?